# issue in navigation bar not hiding in another view controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I have used this code in app delegate for making `breathdatetableviewcontroller` as `rootview controller`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    name =[[NSString alloc]init];
    birthdate =[[NSString alloc]init];
    phone =[[NSString alloc]init];
    email =[[NSString alloc]init];
    image =[[NSString alloc]init];

    birthDateTableViewController =[[BirthDateTableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"BirthDateTableViewController" bundle:nil];

    navController1 = [[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:birthDateTableViewController]autorelease];

    [window addSubview:navController1.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
      [FBProfilePictureView class];


    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];


    self.databaseName = @"birthdateDatabase.sqlite";
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    self.databasePath = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseName];
    [self createAndCheckDatabase];
    //  sleep(5);

    if (sqlite3_open([[self dataFilePath] UTF8String], &database1) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_close(database1);
        NSLog(@"Failed to open db.");
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"Open DB");


    return YES;
}
```

so for solving this problem I try to remove navigation bar and putting following code to make `brithdatetableviewcontroller` as `root view controller`

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.birthDateTableViewController = [[BirthDateTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BirthDateTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.birthDateTableViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

but when I use this then its going in to brithdatetableviewcontroller but not working properly

so lets just stick to what I did before how can I do something like negivation bar should display when its in rootview but it should get hide when it goes into another viewcontroller and those viewcontroller have there own nevigationbar and buttons.

I tried to hide it in another viewcontroller and but thats not working here.

please suggest what should I do to come over this?

Answer (score 0):

**In the viewController**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // If you wnat Navigation Bar then
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
    // Else if you don't want
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: i tried this its not working. used this   [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES]; for hiding but nothing happen

Comment: i have one question will it hide the main navigation bar or will it just hide all navigation bar?

Answer (score 0):

1. In your **AppDelegate.h** class, create a navigation controller :

   @property(nonatomic,strong)UINavigationController *navController;
2. In your  **APPDELEGATE.M**, assign the local Navigation Contooler object to the property.

   (UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

   UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:<**MYViewController**>];

   **self.navController = nav;**

   [self.window addSubview:nav.view];

   }